# Flutter Error: The method 'jsonEncode' is not defined

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http, mobile

I am attempting to create a put request to an API using Flutter using the following function:

```
Future<http.Response> login(String username, String password) {
    return http.put(
        Uri.parse('apiurl'),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(
            <String, String>{'username': username, 'password': password}));
  }
```

The issue I am running into is that it keeps erroring out at the `jsonEncode` line, saying it is not defined.  I have included the following packages:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

What am I missing to make the `jsonEncode` function exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import:

```
import "dart:convert";
```

- [Dart-convert-library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  There was no information regarding that import in the places i looked.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your file, add this import:

```
import "dart:convert";
```

as you can see from its documentation, it belongs to the dart's convert package:

[jsonEncode](https://api.dart.dev/be/175791/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html)

[jsonDecode](https://api.dart.dev/be/175791/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html)